# How to change color of the input during an error in Quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I am very new to Quasar and I am trying to override the current background color when there is an error in the rules, but there is no success which I believe is caused due to the CSS being implemented after the CSS is loaded.

My code at the moment.

```
<q-input :style="{ width: '100%' }" standout="bg-dark text-white"
        :input-style="{ color: 'white', fontSize: '1.2em' }" color="primary" label="Username" roun
        v-model="props.username" :rules="usernameRules" />
```

I tried targeting the classes in CSS but it did not work.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
<form @submit.prevent.stop="onSubmit" @reset.prevent.stop="onReset" class="q-gutter-md">
<q-input ref="usernameRef" :standout="mystandout" color="primary" label="Username"  v-model="username" :rules="usernameRules" />

</template>
<script setup>

let mystandout = ref('bg-dark text-white')
let usernameRef = ref(null)
function onSubmit () {
usernameRef.value.validate()
if (usernameRef.value.hasError) {
          mystandout.value = 'bg-red text-white'
        }
}
```

something like that i suppose